# Javascript game of life array gets reset

Tags: javascript, arrays, grid

For a fun little project I decided to program conway's game of life in javascript. My logic seems to make sense and each individual function does its job however I still dont get my intended result. I have an array called grid, which stores the value of all the cells, and if they are alive or dead. I check each individual cell, then check all 8 surrounding cells to count neighbors, repeat for every other cell. At some point my grid no longer stores the correct value and resets. At this point I'm starting to think it's a javascript problem.

```html
<body>
  <style>
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    body {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    canvas {
      background: #FFFFFF;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  </style>
  <canvas id="canvas" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
</body>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  var Game = {};
  var nextGrid, emptyGrid, grid;
  Game.horCells = 30;
  Game.cellSize = canvas.width / Game.horCells;
  Game.verCells = Math.floor(canvas.height / Game.cellSize);
  Game.startLives = 80;

  config();
  //setInterval(run, 1000);

  function config() {
    console.log("in config");
    emptyGrid = newGrid(Game.horCells, Game.verCells);
    grid = emptyGrid;
    nextGrid = emptyGrid;
    //Manual Setup
    for (var i = 0; i < Game.startLives; i++) {
      //grid[getRandomInt(0, Game.horCells - 1)][getRandomInt(0, Game.verCells - 1)] = true;
    }
    grid[0][3] = true;
    grid[1][3] = true;
    grid[2][3] = true;
  }

  function run() {
    console.log("gread" + grid[3][3]);
    draw();
    update();
  }


  function draw() {
    console.log("Draw");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < Game.horCells; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < Game.verCells; j++) {
        if (grid[i][j] === false) {
          ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
        } else if (grid[i][j] === true) {
          console.log("drawing live");
          ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        }
        ctx.fillRect(i * Game.cellSize, j * Game.cellSize, Game.cellSize, Game.cellSize);
      }
    }
  }

  function update() {
    for (var p = 0; p < Game.horCells; p++) {
      for (var k = 0; k < Game.verCells; k++) {
        nextGrid[p][k] = survival(p, k);
      }
    }
  }

  function survival(x, y) {
    var neighbours = 0;
    for (var l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
      for (var m = 0; m < 3; m++) {
        var sx = (x - 1) + l;
        var sy = (y - 1) + m;
        //Check bounds
        if (inBounds(sx, sy) === true && grid[sx][sy]) {
          neighbours++;
        }
      }
    }
    if (grid[x][y]) {
      neighbours--;
      if (neighbours === 2 || neighbours === 3) {
        return true;
      } else if (neighbours < 2 || neighbours > 3) {
        console.log("DIED");
        return false;
      }
    } else if (grid[x][y] === false && neighbours === 3) {
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log("DIED");
      return false;
    }
  }

  function inBounds(x, y) {
    return (x >= 0 && x < Game.horCells && y >= 0 && y < Game.horCells);
  }

  function newGrid(xCells, yCells) {
    var gridd = new Array(xCells);
    for (var i = 0; i < xCells; i++) {
      gridd[i] = new Array(yCells);
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < xCells; j++) {
      for (var k = 0; k < yCells; k++) {
        gridd[j][k] = false;
      }
    }
    return gridd;
  }


  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "At some point my grid no longer stores the correct value and resets"? Javascript arrays don't simply stop working. The web would be horribly broken if that were the case.

Comment: `emptyGrid = newGrid(Game.horCells, Game.verCells);
    grid = emptyGrid;
    nextGrid = emptyGrid;` looks a tad sketchy. You're assigning both references to the same mutable grid. Try creating 2 separate empty grids.

Comment: Also, you never appear to swap `newGrid` and `grid`.

Comment: I apologize if that was too vague! It seems that after iterating over a live cell and continuing, without changing the value of the cell, that same cell is then dead on the next iteration. I dont have any code to set the value of the cell. Only to set the value of the nextGrid cell.

Comment: Look at my second comment. I'll write an answer in a sec.

Comment: I removed the swap in order to test the bug by running the main loop manually to trace the problem and never was able to find it. But you're right I must add that back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
emptyGrid = newGrid(Game.horCells, Game.verCells);
grid = emptyGrid;
nextGrid = emptyGrid
```

Creates *1* grid, then assigns `grid` and `nextGrid` to the *same object*. Again, `grid` and `nextGrid` are the same object. Any changes you make to 1 will happen to the other.

Create 2 separate grids so they can be changed independently:

```
grid = newGrid(Game.horCells, Game.verCells);
nextGrid = newGrid(Game.horCells, Game.verCells);
```

Or, to neaten it up slightly:

```
var g = () => newGrid(Game.horCells, Game.verCells);

grid = g();
nextGrid = g();
```

---

Just to clear up the question in the comments:

```
var g = () => newGrid(Game.horCells, Game.verCells);
```

Is (basically) the same thing as:

```
var g = function() {
    return newGrid(Game.horCells, Game.verCells);
}
```

It's known as a "fat-arrow" function.

Both bits do the same thing though: they create a function that returns a new grid. This has the benefit of not needing to write `newGrid(Game.horCells, Game.verCells);` twice.

I used an arrow function instead of the `function` keyword because the latter is giant and ugly, which takes away from the goal of cleaning up the code.

Comment: Thank you so much! this all makes sense now. I assumed that assigning the value of one to the other would only assign it's current state. And so I could refer to emptyGrid if ever i needed to get a clean grid without having to regenerate one.

Comment: @ArinYaldizciyan No problem. And no; if you want that behavior, you need to work with immutable data structures. Look up the Immutable.js library, or a language like Clojurescript (which compiles into JavaScript).

Comment: Another final question! Your solution uses the notation =>, what is the function of this notation? Thank you once again :)

Comment: @ArinYaldizciyan I'll add an update to the answer. It's the new anonymous function syntax.

Comment: @ArinYaldizciyan Added.

Comment: Perfect answer! Super well explained. Solved all my problems completely. I thought I was going insane!

Comment: @ArinYaldizciyan Np. I'd appreciate an upvote too if you're able. I can't remember if new users can upvote answers.

Comment: I have! However apparently new users upvotes aren't seen publicly

Comment: @ArinYaldizciyan Oh right, that's the restriction. Oh well. Thanks.